# Angular CLI refresh content on change route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an Angular CLI app.

In the app I have a map (on the right side) and left panel (which shows current information about route). If I click on map, the openlayers find the nearest feature, **and redirects me to /map/routeID/detail**. Everything works like charm (on the TS of detail component I load the data from API and everything if fine).
The problem is... If I click to another place (near some other route) **the URL changes** (so I've been redirected to another route detail). **But the informations are old (from the other route).** I'm doing loading in NgOnInit, I tried to print console string and I found out the NgOnInit is not called when my route changes from fox example /map/1/detail to /map/2/detail.

How can I handle this? For example If the route changes, the NgOnInit is triggered again or something like this.

Comment: Try `ngOnChanges(){ this.ngOnInit();}`

Comment: It doesnt work too.

Comment: `NgOnInit` will only trigger when the component is created. While you are on that single route, I don't believe that it will trigger again. How are you getting the routeID param in your NgOnInit? If you subscribe to `ActivatedRoute` param changes to get that you should have what you need https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Yea Im using this.routeId = this.activateDroute.snapshot.params['id']; for getting route ID from URL. How can I subscribe to that params? And in the subscription I need to call NgOnInit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to watch for changes to the route parameters instead of just getting the initial value as in your comment. To do this you will need to subscribe to one of the observables (e.g. `paramMap` https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) on the `ActivatedRoute` object and then run the code that is needed on every route change.

```
@Component({...})
class ExampleComponent {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(map => {
            // run code to process
        });
    }
}
```

As a note, the `paramMap` subscription does not need to be unsubscribed from [according to the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse) (it is automatically unsubscribed for you).